# CentOS switching to MySQL user

Tags: mysql, centos, sudo

I'm wondering is it even possible to use the MySQL user as one of the login to retrieve some data via FTP?

Such as:

su mysql (And if so, what could the password be, the default one or where in some point was I able to change it? )

Answer (score 1):

By default on a CentOS system the mysql account is locked

```
passwd -S mysql
mysql LK 2012-08-29 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
```

If you look at the shadow file entry

```
mysql:!!:15581::::::
```

You'll see that there isn't a valid password set. If you want you can always set a password using the [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd) command and unlock it using passwd too.